# ndbclient native library is missing in Mysql Cluster installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I'm trying to run ClusterJ which cannot find ndbclient library.
In my MySql Cluster 7.4 installation under Windows I have ndbclient_static.lib file in lib catalog. Why ndbclient library is not there? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 packages in 7.4 release: ZIP and MSI. I have found library in ZIP package.